# Does RestSharp API documentation exist?

Tags: restsharp

We're trying to use RestSharp, as it seems to be the preferred software for REST communications. However, there doesn't seem to be any thorough documentation *anywhere*. The restsharp.org site has a couple of simple examples, and it refers to the GitHub site (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki) for documentation. That covers a lot more, but still not that much. Otherwise, the RestSharp site just links back to StackOverflow.

Is there a good document that describes RestSharp methods and usage in detail? (I'll probably feel like an idiot when someone points out the obvious, but I'm just not seeing it!)

Thanks!